# Vue JS 3 Composition API useStorage not showing content on page

Tags: vue.js, axios, fetch, vueuse

I have this project where I must import some data through fetch. It seems it works for that matter but I have to use useStorage for the sake of global state and such. So, problem is I get the data and it gets logged but it seems it doesn't get stored or something is wrong with showing it on the page. The official doc is not so clear and doesn't state anything about data fetch so I'm not sure what's wrong. All I get is an empty { } in the page, the data log seems correct but the "imported data" log seems wrong. Can you understand what's wrong about it?

The App.vue code is

```
<script>

import state from "./stores/listStore";

export default {
  setup () {
    const listStore = state
    console.log(listStore)
    return {listStore}
  }
}

</script>

<template>
  <div id="main">
    {{ listStore }}
  </div>
</template>
```

The listStore.js code is

```
import { useStorage } from "@vueuse/core";
import axios from "axios";

const theDefault = fetchData();

const state = useStorage('vue-use-local-storage', theDefault)

  async function fetchData() {
    try {
      const data = await axios.get("https://ott-fogliata.github.io/vuejs-s2i-repository/cultured-meat.json");
      for (let i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
    data.data[i]["quantity"] = 0;
      }
      console.log(data)
      return data.data;
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  export default state
```

[image]

Comment: The question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors